# How to transfer frozen NFT's

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, metaplex, nft

I've got a problem. I can't send NFT in my JS code, or rather include in transaction token NFT account which has `state - frozen`. How can I unfreeze it? I've seen an example that I need to use Metaplex.

But can I add this to my main transaction, and then use already unfrozen token account and include it in `TransferInstruction` ? Or it's incorrect??

```
import { transferV1 } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

let transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction();

const unfreeze = await transferV1(umi, {
  mint,
  authority: currentOwner,
  tokenOwner: currentOwner.publicKey,
  destinationOwner: newOwner.publicKey,
  tokenStandard: TokenStandard.NonFungible,
}).transaction.add(unfreeze)
```

Maybe Is there any other ways to unfreeze a token account? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your token account is frozen, so you need to unfreeze it first before being able to transfer anything. For this you need to own the Keypair in charge of the FreezeAuthority and then use it to execute a `ThawAccount` instruction on your account. From the [docs](https://spl.solana.com/token):

> The Mint may also contain a freeze_authority which can be used to issue FreezeAccount instructions that will render an Account unusable. Token instructions that include a frozen account will fail until the Account is thawed using the ThawAccount instruction. The SetAuthority instruction can be used to change a Mint's freeze_authority. If a Mint's freeze_authority is set to None then account freezing and thawing is permanently disabled and all currently frozen accounts will also stay frozen permanently.

Comment: So without Keypair of the FreezeAuthority i can't do anything? So sad...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that's the answer.